# Update ng-repeat after function

Tags: angularjs

I have build a piece of angular code but the ng-repeat should show after i called the function. I checked if the http.get function actually returns data and that is true it returns a list formatted like this:

```
[{id:"183m-WQHGaNHP-uVhuvJONyVKLAG", title:"a title"},{id:"183m-WQHGaNHP-uVhuvJONyVKLAG", title:"a title"}]
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="driveController as drive">
<div ng-repeat="f in drive.documents">
  <pre>{{f | json}}
  </pre>
</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller('driveController', ['$scope', 'driveLoad', function($scope, driveLoad) {

    $scope.documents = driveLoad.files;
    driveLoad.getFiles("root"); 

  }]);

  app.service('driveLoad', ['$http', function($http, id) {
    var files = [];
    var jsonTransform = function (data, headers) {
      return angular.fromJson(data);
    };
    return {
        getFiles: function (id) {
          $http.get('/svc', {
            transformResponse:jsonTransform,
            params:{'file_id':id}
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            angular.copy(data, files);
          });
        },
        files: files
    }
  }]);


})();
```

Comment: Are you sure about the format that you've stated for that list - its not valid Json. (probably needs some `{}`)

Comment: Im sure the that it returns a list. I tried with var files = {}; but then it returned to me that the copy function did not work because data and files where not the same object.

Comment: It's not invalid due to missing `{}`, it's invalid due to lots of missing `" "` around the strings (i.e. it should be `title: "a title"`).

Comment: I copied the list from the http response so its a bit messy. i've edited the correct response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `transformResponse` function, just remove it entirely.

Also, I believe when using the syntax `controller as somevariable`, you should assign things to the scope using `this` instead of `$scope`.

So in your case, change `$scope.documents = driveLoad.files;` to `this.documents = driveLoad.files;`

Other than that, your code is correct as far as I can see.

Correct code:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller('driveController', ['$scope', 'driveLoad', function($scope, driveLoad) {

    this.documents = driveLoad.files;
    driveLoad.getFiles("root"); 

  }]);

  app.service('driveLoad', ['$http', function($http, id) {
    var files = [];
    return {
        getFiles: function (id) {
          $http.get('/svc', {
            params:{'file_id':id}
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            angular.copy(data, files);
          });
        },
        files: files
    }
  }]);


})();
```